# Query UTM grid for elevation at specific lat/lon coordinates

Tags: python, elevation, proj

I need to query UTM grid data (25 meters) for elevation at specific coordinates in lat/lon form.

The UTM data uses the following proj parameters: `+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`.

I already know how to convert the UTM coordinates to lat/lon using pyproj and if I only needed to get elevation for already defined coordinates, it would be fine.
But what do I do when the requested coordinate is somewhere inside the grid?
What do I need to do to get (computed) elevation data for coordinates inside the fields created by the point grid of my data?

This converts the UTM coordinates into lat/long:

```
from pyproj import Proj

myproj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
lat, lon = myproj(420150.000, 5530000.000, inverse=True)

print(f"lat: {lat} / lon: {lon}")
```

A couple of examples from the data file:

```
420000.000 5530000.000 180.899
420025.000 5530000.000 177.564
420050.000 5530000.000 175.212
420075.000 5530000.000 173.590
420100.000 5530000.000 171.928
420125.000 5530000.000 170.413
420150.000 5530000.000 168.032
420175.000 5530000.000 165.155
420200.000 5530000.000 165.586
420225.000 5530000.000 169.378
420250.000 5530000.000 171.779
420275.000 5530000.000 174.764
420300.000 5530000.000 177.127
420325.000 5530000.000 178.026
420350.000 5530000.000 177.593
420375.000 5530000.000 176.215
420400.000 5530000.000 174.241
420425.000 5530000.000 171.916
420450.000 5530000.000 169.504
420475.000 5530000.000 167.347
420500.000 5530000.000 164.525
420525.000 5530000.000 160.327
```

*Edit*: I think I need to say that I'm a GIS novice. I'm basically doing this because for my area there is no web service (WMS or WCS) that serves me this data but only a download with an archive of DGM25_xxxyyyy.xyz files, so I'm forced to code a service/application that'll handle the queries myself. I have experience in programming but not in GIS and I feel a bit lost.

Until now I imported different web services and data into QGIS to check them out until I was (kind of) satisfied with the DGM25 data. QGIS was also nice enough to give me the proj parameters I wrote above after I found the correct CRS for the data (verified by comparing it to an OSM layer).